# English Translation Error in Psalm 118:26 on Chabad.org?

Tags: translation, tehilim-psalms, mistakes

If we go online to chabad.org and read the English translation of [Psalm 118:26](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16339/jewish/Chapter-118.htm), we currently read:

> "Blessed be he who has come in the name of the Lord; we have blessed you in the name of the Lord."

However the Hebrew words in Tehillim 118:26 state **מִבֵּ֥ית יְהֹוָֽה** which traditionally means in English:

> from-[the] House of [the LORD]

Why would chabad.org use "Name of the Lord" (twice) when translating Psalm 118:26 in English?

Comment: the malbim explains it as שהברכה יוצאת מביתו מאת השוכן בו which isn't exactly as the translation has it, but it is a step closer.

Comment: You're bothered they translated מבית as "in the name"?

Comment: I deleted my comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me they are basing themselves on the [Radak](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Tehillim/118.26#e0n6) who wrote:

> ברוך הבא בשם י״י – ברכנו אתכם מבית י״י ותהיו מבורכים בשמו כי הוא אל יכול, והוא יחיד נמצא והוא האיר לנו מאפילה שהיינו בה בגלות לפיכך בואו ועבדו את י״י כמונו

which seems to say that being blessed in the name of Hashem is part of the second half of the passuk. However, I personally think that the Radak is explaining both halves of the passuk, but he switched the order because he goes into more detail on the first half of the passuk than the second.